# C# прокси сервер авторизация

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient

в приложение есть форма где заполняется хост,порт, логин и пароль

```
string loginProxy = Properties.Settings.Default.LoginProxy;
string passwordProxy = Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordProxy;
string hostProxy = Properties.Settings.Default.Host;
string portProxy = Properties.Settings.Default.Port;
string uriSetting = hostProxy + ":" +  portProxy;

Uri baseUri = new Uri(url);
Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, uriSetting);

HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(string.Format("{0}:{1}", hostProxy, portProxy), false),                    
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    //Credentials = new NetworkCredential("123", "!23")
};
```

пытаюсь настроит логин и пароль

```
    httpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(loginProxy, passwordProxy);    

    var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

когда делаю запрос выдает ошибку 407

```
   var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, loginModel);
```

пожалуйста помогите, не могу сам решить

Comment: Код выглядит правильно, я вот только не помню что означает PreAuthenticate . Код 407 означает, что логин/пароль на прокси не считается валидным.

Comment: Если прокси поставить без логина и пароля зохидит